# viewLifecycleOwner gets null value when working with DrawerLayout

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-livedata

I have the following function in my Fragment -

```kotlin
private fun getOffenderInfo(device: BleDevice) {
        val offenderInfoRequest = OffenderInfoBody(activity?.sharedPreferences?.deviceId, activity?.sharedPreferences?.token, listOf(TagItem(device.tagID)))
        offenderViewModel.getOffenderInfo(offenderInfoRequest).observe(viewLifecycleOwner, { offenders ->
            when (offenders) {
                is Resource.Loading -> {
                }
                is Resource.Success -> {
                    updateUI(offenders.data, device)
                }
                is Resource.Exception -> {
                }
            }
        })
    }
```

Which is triggered by me finding a BLE device -

```kotlin
private fun initViews() {
        
        //.....Other not relevant code

        bleManager = BLEManager { bleDevice ->
            handleDeviceFound(bleDevice)
        }

    }

 // Handle BLE device found
    private fun handleDeviceFound(device: BleDevice) {
        // check if bleDevice with this TAG_ID already exist in bleDevices
        bleDevices.find { it.tagID == device.tagID } ?: return addDevice(device)
        if (device.bleOffender == null || device.bleOffender?.status == -1)
            return getOffenderInfo(device)
        val offenderDeviceData = tagDecryption.parseTagData(device, tagDecryption.decryptOffenderDetails(device))
        handleDeviceData(offenderDeviceData)
    }

    // adding new device to bleDevices & update adapter
    private fun addDevice(device: BleDevice) {
        bleDevices.add(device)
        tagsAdapter.addDevice(device)
        binding.fragmentScannerClearButton.isEnabled = bleDevices.isNotEmpty()
       return getOffenderInfo(device)


    }
```

And is calling a method in my ViewModel that access both local and remote data -

```kotlin
 fun getOffenderInfo(offenderInfoBody: OffenderInfoBody) = liveData(Dispatchers.IO) {
        emit(Resource.Loading<Nothing>())
        emit(offenderRepository.getOffenderInfo(offenderInfoBody))
    }
```

The issue is that, when I am switching between Fragments in my DrawerLayout during BLE scan and the livedata observer is starting to obverse, the app is crashing with the following error

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't access the Fragment View's LifecycleOwner when getView() is null i.e., before onCreateView() or after onDestroyView()`

The Fragment is one of 3 fragments that are accessable via DrawerLayout.

I can switch without any problems if I am not during scan.

As far as I know, the livedata functionallity should not cause this issue and just stop the observer, though it doesn't.

What am I missing?

edit -

My BLEManager class -

```kotlin
class BLEManager(private val onBleScanResult: (device: BleDevice) -> Unit) : BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback {

    override fun onLeScan(device: BluetoothDevice?, rssi: Int, scanRecord: ByteArray?) {
        if (scanRecord == null || device == null) return
        // siteCode validation indicates that tag is SuperCom tag
        val siteCode = scanRecord[5].toInt() and 0xFF
        val tagID: Int = (scanRecord[6].toInt() and 0xFF) + (scanRecord[7].toInt() and 0xFF) * 256 + (scanRecord[8].toInt() and 0xFF) * 65536
        // validate TagId isn't equals to 0
//            if (tagID != 0 && (tagID == 2467 || tagID == 3004)) { }// remove *&& (tagID == 2467 || tagID == 3004)* in production (used only for testing)
        if (tagID == 0) return
        val bleDevice = BleDevice(device = device, tagID = tagID.toString(), rssi = rssi, scanRecord = scanRecord)
        onBleScanResult(bleDevice)
    }
}
```

Comment: where are you calling "initViews()"?

Comment: @SinneroftheSystem on 'onViewCreated()'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the easiest way to fix it is stop the scan when the fragment is destroyed

```
override fun onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView()
    bleScanner.stopScan(bleManager)
}
```

Comment: show the implementation of this function "BLEManager { bleDevice -> }"

Comment: Added to main post